# Need to return a list based on Slug

Tags: search, slug

I need a search field to return only a specific slug when the user types it.

Basically, I need to create pages for students and each student page will be displayed only when user types the page slug in the search box (it will work as a password).

Is there any plugin that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Asking for plugin or theme recommendations is considered "off topic" for WPSE. You may want to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi I will promptly edit my question, but could you clarify why recommendations of plugins considered Off Topic and what WPSE means? Is there anywere else I should post this?

Comment: WPSE is how we abbreviate *this* site's name, which is part of StackExchange (the "SE" in WPSE). Here are help articles re: [what's on topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what's not](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). As to "why," it's because they are matters of opinion and attract spammy answers. (However, when it comes to *answering* a question, plugin recommendations *are* OK.) The more specific the scope of your question, the more specific the answers will be.